# how to authenticate on premise crm configured with public ip and http connection through windows phone 8

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-8, dynamics-crm

my crm is on premise configured with public ip and http connection

ex- http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555

i have to authenticate and gain access to crm from windows phone 8 application.but won't able to access it.

it always showing null reference exception in OrgServiceConfiguration_MetadataLoadFailure function

but i can access it through windows form application and able to retrieve organization

code-

IServiceConfiguration OrgServiceConfiguration OrgServiceConfiguration = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration(new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555/ymf/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"), metadataLoaded);
 OrgServiceConfiguration.MetadataLoadFailure += new EventHandler(OrgServiceConfiguration_MetadataLoadFailure);

Comment: What Windows phone application do you use? As I know, if you use CRM 2013 and Microsoft APP for Windows 8.1 you have to use HTTPS and Internet Facing Deployment to connect with the app. Maybe this is also relevant for your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SDK supported code available to connect from a Windows Phone 8 (or Windows 8) application to Dynamics CRM that is not running as claims-based/IFD.

You will need to create your own connection code which supports Windows Authentication or, the easier and supported move, update your Dynamics CRM deployment to use claims-based/IFD.

Comment: But i am able to access the server From Windows form application using  the API of SDK provided by Microsoft

Comment: But i am able to access the server From Windows form application using  the API of SDK provided by Microsoft. But That API works for only .net framework, which is not supported by Windows phone. so, i have to use different SDK for Windows phone 8

Comment: Correct, the SDK that works for Windows Phone 8 does __not__ support Windows Authentication. You can do it from a WinForm app but not a WindowsPhone App - it's just that simple.